# Angular js ng-class not working in google chrome but working in firefox

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

I am new to using angular js, I'm confused, I have code like this

```js
angular.module("sportStore")
  .constant("productListActiveClass", "btn-primary")
  .controller("productListCtrl", function($scope, $filter, productListActiveClass) {

    var selectedCategory = null;

    $scope.selectCategory = function(newCategory) {
      selectedCategory = newCategory;
    }

    $scope.categoryFilterFn = function(product) {
      return selectedCategory == null ||
        product.category == selectedCategory;
    }

    $scope.getCategoryClass = function(category) {
      return selectedCategory == category ? productListActiveClass : "";
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default row" ng-controller="productListCtrl">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <a ng-click="selectCategory()" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">Home</a>
    <a ng-repeat="item in data.products | orderBy:'category' | unique: 'category'" ng-click="selectCategory(item.category)" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" ng-class="getCategoryClass(item.category)">
                    {{item.category}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

then when i try it, result in chrome as follows:

[result in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlmXn.png)

and in firefox as follows:

[result on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvyDS.png)

can somebody tell me why this happened? ng-class work on firefox but not in chrome. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that cache in chrome must be cleaned before. it worked now in chrome.